# Laravel 5.7: Best approch do javascript block

Tags: javascript, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

What is the best approach to implement a custom script (modal alert - error or success) to save code and work.

Custom tag, called on the blade view?

Comment: You can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50198419/laravel-5-js-is-blocking-by-app-js/50198831) it can help you

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I like to do with script files that I only want to load on specific pages.

For my layout.blade.php file I will have:

```
<html>
<body>
    @yield('content')
    @include('pages/partials/footer-scripts')
    @yield('additional-scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

So I will include my standard footer scripts, and then yield anything else than needs to be added in the specific blade file like this:

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')
<h1>Some content</h1>
@endsection

@section('additional-scripts')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/modal-alert.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

But if you want to use the script everywhere you can put it in 'pages/partials/footer-scripts.blade.php'

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/modal-alert.js') }}"></script>
```

So the above will be loaded in all blade files that extends your default layout file.

Comment: If the script is supposed to appear on all pages, it will be better to use 'mix' to combine and minify all your js (and also css) files. So it will put your modal-alert.js inside app.js along with all your other js. You can read about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix.